# Creating a precise time interval with no drift over long periods of time

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to run a long running task that remains in a loop. The code in the loop must only execute at the same time interval. Probably the most common way to handle this is using an interval timer. Problem with an interval timer is that it isn't exact. If I plotted the absolute time whenever the timer fires, there would be small amounts of drift over a long period. This isn't an issue if the interval time is fairly large, such as hundreds of milliseconds or more. But it does become an issue if the interval is only tens of milliseconds.

Whenever a time interval occurs, this interval must occur relative to a starting point before the loop was entered. It must not be a time interval that starts when the last one ends, otherwise you can end up with an accumulated drift over time.

There is also the issue that if the code in the timer block takes too long to complete within the time interval, as soon as the interval expires, I'm not sure, but I believe the timer starts immediately. This would result in uneven time intervals from one loop to the next.

The only solution I can think of is to record the system clock before the loop starts. I'll refer to this as the "start time". It only exists once and is never overwritten. Then after the loop's code completes, measure the time difference from the current time and the start time and determine which time interval we are at by dividing the difference by the rate at which we want the loop to execute. If the current time interval hasn't been reached, either sleep until the time expires or just keep looping and measuring the time difference until the current interval has expired.

Is there perhaps a better solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “interval timer”?

Comment: Execute the code in the loop, say every 30 ms. The time interval is 30 ms.

Comment: And you chose Java to implement this?

Comment: Java or Kotlin. It's an Android app that needs to handle this.

Comment: I sounds like anything to do with thread scheduling (sleeping, scheduled thread execution) may not be precise enough. An alternative is to constantly spin in a loop, check the time pretty much as you described and then either execute or continue spinning. That may be expensive in terms of CPU, but hey, you did want fine control.

Answer (score 1):

## `ScheduledExecutorSerivce`

If I understand your Question, and I may well not, you are simply asking about how to time a repeated task on a strict schedule given that the execution of the task takes time and can therefore throw off the schedule.

If I understand that correctly, then you are discussing the effective difference between the two [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) methods:

- [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))
- [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

If you want a task to start on the minute, and run every minute, you would first calculate an initial delay until the next minute strikes. Then you would secondly call the first method, [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), to plan for the next minute elapsed since the first minute rather than elapsed when the task’s execution completed.

If you want to wait for the task’s execution to complete before commencing with the task again, call the second method, [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

## Drift is unavoidable

As noted in the Javadoc for `ScheduledExecutorService`, you cannot expect perfect timing without drift in a conventional Java app running on conventional hardware with a conventional operating system.

If you want a rhythm of tens of milliseconds with no drift over time, I expect you will be disappointed. Processes and threads are routinely suspended in unpredictable ways for unpredictable lengths of time by the OS and hardware, thereby interrupting your carefully-timed task to be run. Within the JVM, garbage-collection and other events may also suspend your carefully-timed task in unpredictable ways.

If you truly need such precision, you should investigate [real time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java) implementations.

### Sample code

I tried the following code as an experiment.

I tried to warm the executor service by running the task once, then waiting a couple seconds.

For easier reading of timestamps, my intent is to start the repeating task at the top of the next minute. On that my code does not fare well, starting 6 milliseconds tardy. For example: `Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.006474Z`.

After that, the scheduled executor service does a pretty good job of keeping a 10 millisecond rhythm. In example below, we hit 12 ms, 23 ms, 33, 43, 52, 63, 73, 83, 92, 103, and so on. I do not have time now to pursue it longer to watch for drift over an hour.

```java
// Prepare the background thread.
final long fixedRateInNanos = Duration.ofMillis( 10 ).toNanos();
Runnable runnable = ( ) -> System.out.println( "Now: " + Instant.now() );
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.submit( runnable );  // Warm the executor service and backing thread pool.
try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 2 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

// Calculate the schedule.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
Duration d = Duration.between( now , now.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ).plusMinutes( 1 ) );
long initialDelayInNanos = d.toNanos();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( runnable , initialDelayInNanos , fixedRateInNanos , TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );

// Wait a while for app to run.
try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes( 2 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
ses.shutdown();
try { ses.awaitTermination( Duration.ofSeconds( 10).toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
System.out.println( "INFO - `main` done running. " + Instant.now() );
```

When run from IntelliJ 2021.1.1 RC using Java 16 on macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, on a Mac mini with 6 real Intel cores and no hyper-threading.

```
Now: 2021-04-30T07:38:51.444455Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.006474Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.012990Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.023869Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.033129Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.043817Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.052992Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.063646Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.073201Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.083842Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.092991Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.103702Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.113141Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.123775Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.132995Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.143679Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.153165Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.163813Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.172826Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.183647Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.193121Z
Now: 2021-04-30T07:39:00.203783Z
```

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I highly suspect that scheduleAtFixedRate will result in drift over a long period of time. It has no concept of real world time and just fires off at some interval with no regard to a real world clock, and that interval is not a consistent value over time.

Comment: @AndroidDev True. I'm writing a bit more to explain that your intentions as to avoiding drift are not realistic.

Comment: Avoiding drift is very realistic and can be accomplished, at least within an acceptable margin when dealing with a time interval of milliseconds running over a period of say an hour. I think the only solution is to ensure that the time interval is bound to the system clock.

Comment: The OS may suspend a thread, but ultimately once a thread starts to run again, as long as it is tied to the system clock and the system clock is highly accurate, the time interval will be accurate. You may still get a dealy on any particular interval but there will be no drift relative to real time. I didn't mention that my code will be running on a mobile device, where the system clock is essentially equivalent to that of an atomic clock, giving extremely high accuracy. GPS applications require highly accurate clocks to work with and rely on the system clock for this.

Comment: If accuracy is in the range of some ms it should be possible. But `ScheduledExecutorSerivce` is not the way to go, as to my understanding it may execute different timers in the same Thread, leading to delays. Calculating the time to the next event, sleeping one or two ms shorter than that and then looping seams a way to go (may eat up battery). But there are other pitfalls: Garbage collector may hold all threads for a relevant amount of time. Thread scheduling is another point of concern. I once failed with a similar approach, but my target were 10 microseconds, 10 milliseconds seam possible.

Comment: Yeah, microseconds would probably be pushing it to the limit. There are a lot of applications in the financial trading markets that need to make trades on the order of milliseconds with their times tied to a real system clock because financial markets open and close at precise times and the difference of 50 ms could easily result in a gain or loss of large amounts of money. I think the solution you mention appears to be the only solution.

Comment: @AndroidDev: the apps that need that kind of precision don't run on general purpose OS with a general purpose programming language. They use Realtime OS and specific languages (or variants of languages) to get guarantees. Yes, you can probably get to your goal within *some acceptable margin*, but we have no idea what kind of margin you think of.

Comment: It would be interesting to run the same experiment when all the cores are busy.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do this is to record the time of the next interval, and do the sleep or whatever to try and hit it. When the loop resumes, compare the current time to the target time:

```
val difference = targetTime - currentTime
if (difference > 0) sleep(difference)
else {
  // do thing
  val newTarget = targetTime + interval
  // get current time again because you've spent time doing thing
  sleep(newTarget - newCurrent)
// or check it's not < 1 i.e. you overshot, so just loop again
}
```

So each target time is just the result of adding `interval` multiple times, it's nothing to do with when the loop actually runs. You just have to rely on an accurate clock.

The other thing to watch out for is your actual interval - if it's a nice round number then you'll be fine, if you've calculated it as a fraction (e.g. 1/30 of a second) you'll have inaccuracies in the floating point math, and those will compound as you keep adding that slightly-wrong number. So you might need to recalculate a target time from the start time every so often, at certain "milestones", so you kinda reset the accuracy.